# Django Twitter callback goes to IP-address, not domain

Tags: django, apache, twitter, callback, twitter-oauth

I suddenly got a problem with the twitter redirect going to the IP-adress of my site, not the actual domain, after authorization. This has been working as expected before.

I am using Django for my project, and the IP-adress is in the ALLOWED_HOSTS list. The twitter application itself is correctly figured with the domain, not any IP-adress, it just "chooses" to use the IP, it seems.

Have I misconfigured something server-side maybe? Im a bit of a Django newbie.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "i suddenly got a problem with X" most likely you messed something up between before and after the "suddenly", i highly doubt you'll get any useful answers unless you're lucky to have another user with the exact same issue who managed to solve it show up out of nowhere, so do you have any clue of when this started happening? and if so, what did you change? if you are using version-control try rolling back to when it was working, and do a diff between the two versions to check what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Yes, quiet a specific issue. Found the issue, which was the actual callback url sent to twitter, for others pondering the same issue. Duh!